# Remote site disaster recovery in VMware using DAS storage?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Is it possible to implement disaster recovery of virtual machines in VMware using direct attached storage? What is that feature called and how do you implement it? So that if the primary site loses power you could start the vm on the disaster recovery site.

Comment: This is really vague. Can you outline what you're asking for in greater detail?

Comment: And after searching for "vmware disaster recovery" using your favorite search engines, did you find anything helpful?

Comment: also add srm to your search.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to use either [vSphere Replication](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/replication.html) or a combination of that AND [Site Recovery Manager](http://www.vmware.com/products/site-recovery-manager/overview.html) - depending on your requirements - neither cares about where the VMs are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to look into a software product called Veeam.